# Is it possible to create a list that makes each row linked to a different json file in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a list view and was seeing if it's possible to make each row navigate to a listview that uses a different JSON file. If not, is there any other workaround for it? This is the code I currently have and have tried to switch around the "region" inside the navigationLink to the new JSON file but quickly realized that it does not work.

```
                     NavigationView {
                                Group {
                                    List {
                                        ForEach(regions) { region in 
NavigationLink(destination: RegionListView(regions: region)) {
                                            
                                                RegionButtonView(regions: region)
                                            }
                                        } //: LOOP
                                    } //: LIST
                                } //: GROUP
```

The JSON file is linked to the region. And when I click on a specific region, I want it to take me to another list that is created using a different JSON file. This is the model I made to decode the JSON file that is linked to the list loop.

```
struct Region: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String
}
```

And this is the JSON file I want to make only one of the rows go to. To sum up, I want to make each row navigate to a view that uses a different JSON file.

```
struct SClocations: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let headline: String
    let description: String
    let link: String
    let image: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let address: String
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you are asking for code to do so, probably better to start by posting what you have so far or what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I've added the code to my post @jnpdx

Comment: Your code doesn't mention JSON at all. It might be good to try to approach asking here as if someone isn't familiar with your code at all (because no one is). Explain the issue you're encountering and whenever possible, include a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I changed it again, I hope it's easier to understand. @jnpdx

Comment: You don't say where any of the JSON is coming from. You don't say how `Region` and `SClocations` are connected. You already have a button going to the `Region`. Starting with those reasons, I'm still not seeing where the problem is or really what you're trying to accomplish. But, maybe others will see it more clearly than I do.

Comment: How do I connect `Region` and `SClocations`? I'm pretty new to this. @jnpdx

Comment: I have no idea how `Region` and `SClocations` are related because I don't know anything about your app or your JSON structure.

Comment: Doesn't it show the structure of the JSON file in the structs? I want to make the `SClocations` in a view that comes from clicking the first region. That's how I want to format the app. @jnpdx

Comment: It does show the structure, but there's no mention of how the two are related. Or, where the JSON is coming from in the first place. Try to read your question if you had no prior knowledge of your app -- would it be clear to you what you're asking and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I could see how it would be confusing. So I have a list of regions (Southern California, Desert, Bay Area, etc) and want Southern California to be linked to `SClocations` JSON file when clicked on. Does that help? What do you mean by "Where the JSON is coming form in the first place"? @jnpdx

Comment: I guess that's the first part of the puzzle. So, what's the problem -- what is stopping you from achieving what you're asking?

Comment: I think the question I should have asked is, How do I make each row lead to a different view? @jnpdx

Comment: You already have `NavigationLink(destination: RegionListView(regions: region))` I don't know what `RegionListView` is, but you're sending it a singular region already. What is different about the way this is behaving than what you're looking for?

Comment: It's sending all the regions on the list to the same view. How would I make them each get sent to a different view?@jnpdx

Comment: If you *really* want a completely different view you could do `if x == case1 { NavigationLink() } else if x == case2 { NavigationLink() }` but it would shock me if that's really want you wanted. More likely you want one view that will change based on the parameters that are sent to it

Comment: Yeah but if I did one view that changes based on the parameters, Could I make that view fetch data from a different JSON file depending on which region I click? If not, shouldn't I make an individual view for each with their specific JSON file?@jnpdx

Comment: You should make it one view that fetches a certain file based on the parameters it is sent

Comment: How would I do that? I have 7 different files. @jnpdx

Comment: I will write an answer that shows you at least part of it, but you'd have to give some information on how the program should decide on which file should be chosen. This gets back to where I said it's not at all clear how `Region` and `SClocations` are related. How will the program determine what file should be used?

Comment: It will determine which file on the specific region that clicked.@jnpdx

Comment: I understand. But how? Based on what information? Remember: I have no knowledge about how your program works or how the structs are connected.

Comment: Do you mean the JSON files? That information? I also am not sure what you mean by connected structs.@jnpdx

Comment: I mean that you have not given any information on how file 1 is chosen vs file 2. What parameter is this based on. That's what I mean by connected or related. I'm sorry, I have really tried to help, but I just can't get all the information needed in order to write any sort of answer.

Comment: It's cause I don't know. Like how I see it is if Southern California is chosen then `SClocations` and repeat. So if Bay Area is chosen then their specific JSON file gets chosen. I'm still new that's why I'm trying to learn this, I couldn't find information about it anywhere.@jnpdx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **child** **codable** struct for each type of JSON file you have. Put them in a **parent** struct as optional. Create the List with an array of this parent struct and send each item to the corresponding row detail view. In the row details view, check if any child struct has any value or nil.

Say, you have Dog and Cat type of JSON. Now create two child struct name

```
struct Dog: Codable, Hashable {
    .....
    .....
}

struct Cat: Codable, Hashable {
    .....
    .....
}
```

Now, create the parent struct, Animal as follows

```
struct Animal: Codable, Hashable {
    var cat: Cat?
    var dog: Dog?
}
```

The list will be as follows:

```
var animals = [Animal]

List {
      ForEach(animals) { animal in 
           NavigationLink(destination: RegionListView(regions: animal)) {
               RegionButtonView(regions: region)
           }
      }
}
```

Now, in RegionListView,

```
if let dog = animal.dog {
    showDogListView(dog)
}else if let cat = animal.cat {
    showCatListView(cat)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. For starters, it says that `animals` needs to be identifiable,  and then when I go to the `RegionListView` it doesn't work with the variable. What do you think I'm doing wrong? @Md Razon Hossain

Comment: The code I have provided is just to give you the idea. Please upload your code to git and share it here.